# Trouble waiting for changes to complete that are triggered by Python Playwright `select_option`

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to scrape a site that reports internet service availability by address. Addresses can be selected from a list created for a specific postcode. After an address is selected, a table is updated with the availability of various services.

My problem is that I cannot work out how to spot that the table has been updated after an address is selected. Presumably there's some event on some object that I can wait for, but it's not clear to me what.

Here's my simplistic example - it's reasonably complete to avoid being too abstract:

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect
import time

ign = ["42,", "44,", *list(map(lambda x: f'{chr(x)},', range(ord("A"), ord("J"))))]

def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://checker.ofcom.org.uk/en-gb/broadband-coverage")
    # get rid for cookie legals
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Reject optional cookies and close").click()
    
    # set suitable postcode
    page.get_by_placeholder("Postcode").click()
    page.get_by_placeholder("Postcode").fill("tn13 1xt")
    btn = page.get_by_role("button", name="Set postcode")
    btn.click()
    # find available addresses
    opts = sorted (page.get_by_role("combobox", name="Select your address").inner_text().split ('\n')[1:])

    # remove noise: too many addresses for easy inspection
    for opt in opts.copy():
        for ig in ign:
            if ig in opt:
                try:
                    opts.remove(opt)
                except ValueError:
                    print (f"already removed {opt}")
    print (opts)
    for opt in opts:
        loc = page.get_by_role("combobox", name="Select your address").select_option(label=opt)
        # if the code time.sleep(5) here, the right values are captured
        page.get_by_role("combobox", name="Select your address").wait_for()

        row = page.get_by_role("row", name="Ultrafast")
        row.wait_for()
        cont = row.text_content()
        print (f"status of Ultrafast for {opt}: {cont}")

    context.close()
    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

I get the right answers, but as Eric Morcambe said, not necessarily in the right order, unless I put in an explicit `sleep`, which is counter to the philosophy of Playwright.

To make this practical, I'll have to put it into a `scrapy` framework and use the `async` api, but I need to get something working first.

Suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried [`wait_for_function`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-function)? You can wait for anything, like table contents changing.

Comment: the contents mostly don't change between addresses, so the net would be the same as adding a sleep I think.

Comment: I don't follow--unlike sleeping, waiting for a function polls in a tight loop or waits for the exact state you are waiting for to appear, then immediately releases, so you have essentially perfect precision on the predicate. Sleeping is bad because it either waits too long, wasting time, or releases too soon before the predicate is true. You use `wait_for_function` when the predicate you're waiting for isn't covered by `wait_for_selector` and the other predefined `wait_for`s, so it's a generalization of that pattern where you supply the predicate.

Comment: I don't know what the exact state will be, but nearly always the DOM will not change. I do think that I may be able to use `expect_response` as it looks like the page does request the data. So most of the time, it would wait for a timeout. If I knew how, no doubt I could work out which js was doing that request.

Comment: I see. Yeah, waiting for a response is a good predicate if you can find one. I haven't actually looked at the site in question here, but there's always _something_ that changes or is triggered that you can use instead of a sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ggorlen's suggestion, I spotted that the `select_option` triggered a request, which I was able to trigger on, and validate, thus:

```
        with page.expect_response(lambda response: response.url) as response_info:
            assert loc[0] in response_info.value.url, f"wrong location {response_info.value.url}, expecting {loc}"
```

From this page:
https://playwright.dev/python/docs/network#variations

But note that there seemed to be a bug on that page as `token in` in the lambda function isn't relevant.  The code checks that the query relates to the address of interest.